When is re-indexing triggered after multiple updates
If I have a table in a PostgreSQL database and I want to perform a few thousand of the following statements:
UPDATE table_name SET indexed_col='some', other_col='values' WHERE pk='row-slug';
UPDATE table_name SET indexed_col='other', other_col='values' WHERE pk='row-slug';
.
.
.

If I send these queries at the same time over the CLI app, will re-indexing be triggered after each update statement or after they have all finished?

The index will be modified right when you insert the row, and there is nothing you can do about that.
GIN indexes have a “pending list” that stores new entries without actually adding them to the index tree structure. But that is just an internal detail that is a performance feature — new values are still added to the index for each new row.
Only in the case of loading data with COPY, PostgreSQL tries to be smarter and actually inserts a batch of rows (1000 rows or 65535 bytes, whatever limit is hit first) and then updates the indexes for all these rows.
